# Using getServerSideProps for graphql-codegen mutation in nextjs

Tags: node.js, next.js, server-side-rendering, graphql-codegen

I would like to perform a graphql mutation in `getServerSideProps`. I am using graphql-codegen to generate code from my graphql call. The code I use to perform my mutation is:

```
const [getTokenMutation, _] = useGetTokenMutation()
const token = await getTokenMutation({
```

When I move the working code from the function body to `getServerSideProps` I get the error: `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons ...`

To solve this I looked in to the `graphql-codegen-apollo-next-ssr` plugin for graphql-codegen. Unfortunately this only is generating code for the queries I have defined, not for the mutations.

How can I perform my mutation from getServerSideProps?

Answer (score 2):

The server-side function are Node - not React, so you can't use React hooks in those functions.

You need to call the Apollo client query/mutation in each function. Next.js has multiple Apollo examples - [here is one](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/api-routes-apollo-server-and-client).

---

apollo-client.js

```js
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

export const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "https://example.com/graphql",
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    ...YOUR_SETTINGS
});
```

SomePage.js

```js
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";
import { client } from "./apollo-client";

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    // query
    const { data } = await client.query({query: gql`query SomeQuery {...}`});
    // mutation
    const { data } = await client.mutate({ mutation: gql`mutation getToken {...}`, variables: {} });

}
```

Comment: Would there be a way to still use graphql-codegen to generate a function that I can call from getServerSide props? Then I don't need to write out the query at every point in the code where I would like to use it...

Comment: Another advantage of using graphql-codegen is that it gives me all the types

Comment: It would be best if you wrote your queries & mutations; they are supposed to be specific per component/feature/etc., so you don't over/under fetch. I have a file for each database table with the queries I call, so I only have to write them in one place. I also use gql-codegen to assign types.